# How to avoid repeating long suffix return types at function definition?

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, return-type

Any way to write complex return types like this only at the function declaration?

```
template<typename Xa_t, typename Ya_t, typename Xb_t>
auto interpolate(const Func<Xa_t, Ya_t> & f, const std::vector<Xb_t> & vec) ->
        Func<std::common_type_t<Xa_t, Xb_t>,
            std::conditional_t<std::is_floating_point<Ya_t>::value,
                Ya_t,
                float
            >
        >;
```

If I wanted to define the function after having it declared, I'd have to paste the return type there too, creating a lot of redundancy in the entirety of the code this way.

I am open to both c++11 and c++14 ways. (MSVC preferred)

I guess a similar result can be achieved with preprocessor macros, wouldn't know how to do it that way though.

Comment: I don't think I fully understand.  Could you edit your question to include an example of how you'd like your final code to look?

Comment: edited, imagine the definition the declaration + {}, without somehow the return type specification

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming C++11, a workaround consist in using an [alias template](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias), for instance in your case:

```
template<typename Xa_t, typename Ya_t, typename Xb_t>
using interpolate_return_type = Func<
  std::common_type_t<Xa_t, Xb_t>,
  std::conditional_t<std::is_floating_point<Ya_t>::value,
                     Ya_t,
                     float
                    >
>;
```

Then you can use this alias template in both the declaration and the definition:

```
template<typename Xa_t, typename Ya_t, typename Xb_t>
interpolate_return_type<Xa_t, Ya_t, Xb_t> interpolate(const Func<Xa_t, Ya_t> & f, const std::vector<Xb_t> & vec);

/* ... stuff ...*/

template<typename Xa_t, typename Ya_t, typename Xb_t>
interpolate_return_type<Xa_t, Ya_t, Xb_t>
interpolate(const Func<Xa_t, Ya_t> & f, const std::vector<Xb_t> & vec) {
/* more stuff */
}
```

Comment: Looks great, will work, thank you. Although I don't really understand why there isn't a simple keyword that would copy the return type as described at declaration, since functions cannot differ by return type.

Comment: @AndrewVegvari: With template, function can differ only by return type. [Example](https://ideone.com/U0YENL).